# append children if elements match using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking to append children of matching li elements using jquery. For example

**first list**

```
<ul class="menu1">
  <li>Red</li>
    <ul>
      <li>apple</li>
      <li>rose</li>
    </ul>
  <li>Blue</li>
   <ul>
      <li>sky</li>
      <li>ocean</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

**second list**

```
<ul class="menu2">
  <li>Red</li>
  <li>Blue</li>
</ul>
```

So, I would like to append the sub-lists from the first list to the matching elements of the second list using JQuery.

Here's what I have tried

```
//// create array of menu 1 items
var menuitems = new Array();
$('.menu1 li').each(function(){
  menuitems.push($(this).text);
});

//// create array of menu 2 items

var secondlistitems = new Array();

$('.menu2 li').each(function(){
  secondlistitems.push($(this).text);
});

///// compare and if match append

for (var i = 0; i < menuitems.length; i++) {
for (var j = 0; j < secondlistitems.length; j++) {

       if ($.inArray(secondlistitems[i], menuitems) > -1) {
    menuitems[i].children().appendTo(secondlistitems[j]);
       }
     }
};
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Where are you stuck? Provide your attempt in question, if any...

Comment: Maybe he posted too early by mistake? Anyway, check the :contains-selector! https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you could probably do what you want to do more easily if your HTML was organized slightly better...here is a snippet that works and does what you want to do

```
$(function() {
    $("ul.menu1").children("li").each(function (){
      var subListName = $(this).html();
      var subListContent = $(this).next("ul").clone();
      $(".menu2 li:contains("+ subListName +")").after(subListContent);
    });
});
```

First line: Traverse your `.menu1` and iterate through each `li`s

Second line: get the sublist name

Third line: find the sublist closest `<ul>`, and clone its content

Fourth line: find the matching sublist in `.menu2` and insert the content we just saved next to it

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse each `li` in `.menu2`, match each `li` of `.menu1` against its text and, if matched, clone the `ul` under this `li` and insert the `ul` in `.menu2` in appropriate place

```
     $(function () {
        var menu1 = $('.menu1'),
           menu2 = $('.menu2');

        $('li', menu2).each(function () {
           var m2_li = $(this);
           $('> li', menu1).each(function () {
              if ($(this).text() == m2_li.text()) {
                 $(this).next('ul').clone().insertAfter(m2_li);
              }
           })
        })
     });
```